# Proof about matrix invertibility using matrix norms and infima

Tags: linear-algebra

Let the norm in this question be any matrix norm. Let $I$ be the identity matrix and $A$ be any real-valued square matrix. I'm trying to prove the following statement. If $$\inf_{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}}\| I - \lambda A \| < 1$$ then $A$ is invertible.

I have no idea where to start with this. I know of a theorem on Neumann series that holds when we don't look at the infimum over $\lambda$'s but I don't see how I can use that to prove the statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This conditions imply that there is $\lambda\ne0$ such that
$$
\|I-\lambda A\|<1.
$$
If $\lambda$ would be zero then $\|I-\lambda A\|=\|I\|=1$, so this case is excluded.

This estimate implies that $I-(I-\lambda A)$ is invertible, 
as $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (I-\lambda A)^k$ converges. Hence $\lambda A$ and $A$ are invertible as well.